# Is mincha gedolah better

Tags: zemanim, mincha-afternoon-prayer

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Timing of Mincha](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/2951/timing-of-mincha)

Why do people wait to daven mincha later and not daven mincha gedolah?

Comment: See also: http://mi.yodeya.com/questions/2951/importance-of-mincha